# Rails object structure for reporting metrics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've asked a couple of questions around this subject recently, and I think I'm managing to narrow down what I need to do.

I am attempting to create some "metrics" (quotes because these should not be confused with metrics relating to the performance of the application; these are metrics that are generated based on application data) in a Rails app; essentially I would like to be able to use something similar to the following in my view:

```
@metric(@customer,'total_profit','01-01-2011','31-12-2011').result
```

This would give the total profit for the given customer for 2011.

I can, of course, create a metric model with a custom `result` method, but I am confused about the best way to go about creating the custom metrics (e.g. total_profit, total_revenue, etc.) in such a way that they are easily extensible so that custom metrics can be added on a per-user basis.

My initial thoughts were to attempt to store the formula for each custom metric in a structure with `operand`, `operation` and `operation_type` models, but this quickly got very messy and verbose, and was proving very hard to do in terms of adding each metric.

My thoughts now are that perhaps I could create a custom metrics helper method that would hold each of my metrics (thus I could just hard code each one, and pass variables to each method), but how extensible would this be? This option doesn't seem very rails-esque.

Can anyone suggest a better alternative for approaching this problem?

EDIT: The answer below is a good one in that it keeps things very simple - though i'm concerned it may be fraught with danger, as it uses eval (thus there is no prospect of ever using user code). Is there another option for doing this (my previous option where operands etc. were broken down into chunks used a combination of `constantize` and `get_instance_variable` - is there a way these could be used to make the execution of a string safer)?

Comment: To make things a little clearer: In my current structure (where operands and operations are separated), I could probably use a custom helper, so I could do calculate_metric(@metrics.where(:name => 'profit'),@customer,@start_date,@end_date) - this would work fine. My query is really surrounding the structure of the metric model, and the custom helper to calculate it; what is the best way of doing this so that it is extensible and safe (i.e. does not use eval)? If it is of use, I can edit the question with my current structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was largely answered with some discussion here: [Rails - Scalable calculation model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326904/rails-scalable-calculation-model).

For anyone who comes across this, the solution is essentially to ensure an operation always has two operands, but an operand can either be an attribute, or the result of a previous calculation (i.e. it can be a metric itself), and it is thus highly scalable. This avoids the need to eval anything, and thus avoids the potential security holes that this entails.